# Map list manually from context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, automapper

Initially I was using automapper for this but its seems way harder for me to implement it.

Basically, I just want to return an empty list instead of null values. I can do this on projects level but not on teammates level. The API must not return a null because the UI that consumes it will have an error.

Sample of my implementation below:

```
Projects = !Util.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Projects) ? x.Projects : new List<ProjectsDto>(),
```

Ill highly appreciate if someone can guide me on how to manually map this with null/empty checking.
If you can also provide and example using automapper that too will be very helpful.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    public List<ProjectsDto> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectsDto
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
      
    public List<TeammatesDto> Teammates { get; set; }
}

public class TeammatesDto
{
    public string TeammateName { get; set; }
    public string PreviousProject { get; set; }
}
```

//Get by Id

```
var employee = await _context.Employees
            .Where(x => x.id.Equals(request.Id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

//Map employee

```
 EmployeeDto ret = new EmployeeDto()
 {
    Id = employee.id,
    Name = employee.Name,
    Projects = null //TODO: map manually
 }
```

//Get all employees

```
var employees = await _context.Employees.AsNoTracking()
               .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

//Map here

```
 IList<EmployeeDto> list = new List<EmployeeDto>();
 foreach (var x in employees)
        {
            EmployeeDto dto = new EmployeeDto()
            {
                Id = x.id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Projects = null //TODO: map manually
            };
            list.Add(dto);
        }
return list;
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections). But what fits better is [`ProjectTo`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of materializing full entities, do the following:

```cs
var query = _context.Employees
  .Select(e = new EmployeeDto
     {
        Id = e.id,
        Name = e.Name,
        Projects = e.Projects.Select(p => new ProjectDto
          {
             Status = p.Status,
             Templates = p.Templates.Select(t => new TemplateDto
                {
                    TeammateName = t.TeammateName,
                    PreviousProject = t.PreviousProject 
                }).ToList()
           }).ToList()
      }
  );

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: That's what `ProjectTo` does automatically.

Comment: I know that. Question is how to do that without Automapper.

Comment: Yes, but people can learn :) Clearly the manual solution is painful.

Comment: I'm personally do not use Automapper. And I like control of projections.

Comment: That doesn't scale. For anything other than trivial applications, you need a tool to help. It doesn't have to be AM. But all that repetition, it's mindless.

Comment: I know Expression Tree very well to do not do repetitions. But I do not like reflection style mapping.

Comment: AM works with expression trees, not with reflection. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: I know how AM works. But for generating mapping it maps properties via reflection by property names - that's how it is used usually (not a prop by prop mapping). If you rename entity member, you will loose DTO property mapping and without additional tests you will never track that. Usually each controller method needs unique DTO filling, some properties are not needed, if you stick with AM you will get everything mapped from Database - wasting memory, network, DB resources, speed.

Comment: Configuration validation will catch that automatically. Reusing the same DTO for different use cases is an anti pattern. Rarely a tool is to blame, it's how you use it. Of course you can get great performance with AM, but you have to use it properly.